# When running a bash script within another script, are all variables defined in the parent script inherited to the child?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For example, say I have script1.sh and I need to call script2.sh. Will script2.sh be able to use any variables defined script1.sh? If yes, if I went a step deeper and called script3.sh within script2.sh, would that have access to script1.sh variables?

If not, what would have to be done to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways a variable may be made available for use by a script launched by another script :

- Marking the variable for export (such as with the `export` keyword used at the time of declaration or afterwards, or by using the -`x` option of `declare`, `local` or `typeset`) ;
- Putting an assignment for the variable as a prefix to the command being executed (e.g. `varname=1 command and args`), separated by spaces only ;
- Calling the child script with `source` or `.`, which causes the script to be read and interpreted by the current shell instead of being launched as a separate process, and therefore makes all variables of the current context (including local variables) available to the child script.

Note that marking a variable for export will cause this variable to be copied to the memory space of the child process, and this copy then becomes independent from the variable of the parent shell : modifying it in the child will not change the value in the parent.

Using `source` or `.` is the only way you can cause a child script to modify variables in the parent script, as a child process never has access to the memory space of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Only the exported variables are accessible in the called script:

### 1.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
export exported=1
not_exported=2
2.sh
```

### 2.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
echo $exported
echo $not_exported
```

Running 1.sh only outputs `1`.

You can export a variable only for a dingle call by assigning to it before the call:

```
not_exported=3 2.sh
```