# I don't see why bash eval command does not work as expected?

Tags: bash, eval

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

## My Task

I want to test in a generic way if var is set and not empty.

## The script

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -u
set -o pipefail

if [ $# -ne 1 ] ; then
    echo "num: $#"
    echo "Usage: $0 <VAR_NAME>"
    exit 1
fi
varname=$1

cmd="if [ -z \"\$$varname\" ]; then echo \"$varname is blank or unset\"; else echo \"$varname is set to '\$$varname'\"; fi"

echo "$cmd"
eval "$cmd"
```

this script a based on that site:

[How to check if a variable is set in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash)

## The actual behaviour 1 (it does not work)

if you execute your statement like

```
bla=3
./trv_test_var.sh "bla"
```

you receive the following response:

```
if [ -z "$bla}" ]; then echo "bla is blank or unset"; else echo "bla is set to '$bla'"; fi
./trv_test_var.sh: line 19: bla: unbound variable
```

but if you exceute the outputed command it works as expected:

```
if [ -z "$bla" ]; then echo "bla is blank or unset"; else echo "bla is set to '$bla'"; fi
bla is set to '3'
```

## The actual behaviour 2 (it works but wrongly)

First of all please change the line 14 with the followin code:

```
cmd="if [ -z \${$varname+x} ]; then echo \"$varname is unset\"; else echo \"$varname is set to '\$$varname'\"; fi"
```

Now:

```
bla=3
./trv_test_var.sh "bla"
```

you receive:

```
if [ -z ${bla+x} ]; then echo "bla is blank or unset"; else echo "bla is set to '$bla'"; fi
bla is blank or unset
```

but if you exceute the outputed command it works as expected:

```
if [ -z ${bla+x} ]; then echo "bla is blank or unset"; else echo "bla is set to '$bla'"; fi
bla is set to '3'
```

## The desired behaviour:

I execute the statement with

```
cmd="if [ -z \"\$$varname\" ]; then echo \"$varname is blank or unset\"; else echo \"$varname is set to '\$$varname'\"; fi"
```

and it shows me if the var set or not.

Please help.

Comment: Why do you want to store the command in a variable at all? Don't do that. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: yeah, just put the command text in the script instead of `eval`.  Avoid `eval`.

Comment: Does this a̶n̶s̶w̶e̶r̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶i̶o̶n̶  _help_? [Dynamic variable names in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash)

Comment: Why do you use `eval`? What cannot be done without it, for what you need?

Comment: See [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4154375).

Comment: `bla=3; ./trv_test_var.sh "bla"` doesn't work because the `bla` variable is not visible to the `trv_test_var.sh` program.  See [When running a bash script within another script, are all variables defined in the parent script inherited to the child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43606290/4154375).

Comment: The `unbound variable` error occurs because of `set -u` (equivalent to `set -o nounset`).  There are many difficulties associated with using `set -u`, `set -e` (particularly), and `set -o pipefail`.  See [Bash Pitfalls #60 (set -euo pipefail)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#set_-euo_pipefail) and [BashFAQ/105 (Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is difficult. `eval` is not needed and not that easy to make it work.

But there is a better and much simpler solution. It relies on the indirection functionality offered by Bash in [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). The manual says:

> The basic form of parameter expansion is `${parameter}`. The value of `parameter` is substituted.
> ...
> If the first character of `parameter` is an exclamation point (`!`), and `parameter` is not a *nameref*, it introduces a level of indirection. Bash uses the value formed by expanding the rest of `parameter` as the new `parameter`; this is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the expansion, rather than the expansion of the original `parameter`. This is known as *indirect* expansion.

Your code can be as simple as:

```bash
isset() {
  local varname=$1

  if [ -n "${!varname}" ]; then
    echo "Variable '$varname' is set"
  else
    echo "Variable '$varname' is empty or not set"
  fi
}

FOO=bar

isset FOO
isset BAR
```

You can write a function or a script, the code is the same (the body of the function listed above).

Check it [online](https://tio.run/##hY4xC8IwEIX3@xXPEKgODs7SQQfXgoOLOFzLlQTSRJIgSOlvj0Hq7Hbvvu@O13MypdiUJG93mAlwYWCHF0fPk7T6QHVnR9yx91B63qxkUXgckY34ygEZTIC6cbTcO0GjV62BTajPVbXEJfkvy/TMb4QIH/LvcrS0EF26ru05En3rosZ1Op@uVMoH).

#### Update

It can be done even more simple, without *indirection*. Use `-v` and do not expand the variable that you want to check. Expand only the parameter to find the name of the variable to check:

```bash
isset() {
  local varname=$1

  if [ -v "$varname" ]; then
    echo "Variable '$varname' is set"
  else
    echo "Variable '$varname' is empty or not set"
  fi
}

FOO=bar

isset FOO
isset BAR
```

Check it [online](https://tio.run/##hY4xC8IwEIX3@xWPUKgODs7SQQfXQgcXcbiUKwmkiSShIOJvj0Ha2e3e9747TnMypdiUJO/2eBPgwsgOC0fPs3TNkSqzE@44LFDNyhUeJ2QjvpaAjCZA3Tha1k7QblYLm1Avq2qJS/JflvmZXwgRPuRtc7L0Ibr2fac5Ev1@RY3rdDkPVMoX).

Comment: Yes, ^This. Don't use eval. Indirection or `-v` are much better.

Comment: The function that uses `[ -n "${!varname}" ]` is vulnerable to code injection (`isset 'a[$(rm /)]'`) and a variable name clash (`unset varname; isset varname`).  It also breaks for unset variables if `nounset` is on (`( set -o nounset; unset var; isset var )`).  The function that uses `[ -v "$varname" ]` is also vulnerable to code injection and a variable name clash, though it's OK with `nounset`.  In addition, it doesn't handle a set but empty variable correctly (`var=; isset var`).  It also doesn't work with versions of Bash older than 4.2 (e.g. the default Bash on macOS).

Comment: according to stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/… I only need the command: if [ -z "${!varname}" ]; then echo "$varname is blank or unset"; else echo "$varname is set to '${!varname}'"; fi.

Comment: `-z` and `-n` are opposite. One returns `true` when the argument is empty, the other when it is not empty.

Comment: Don't rely on StackOverflow answers. Many of them are incorrect or have hidden bugs, including this one.